Bare copper wire wrapped around grounding rod
I will soon have a 5/8'' copper bond ground rod installed by an electrician and while discussing the materials needed and the entire process, I was told he'll attach/wrap 16mm2 bare copper wire around the rod in a spiral shape to increase the contact surface, sample shown below:

I've been trying to find some literature on this practice which seems to be quite common in South America which is where I'm writing from but couldn't find any information on why this is done. I'm a bit worried that having a spiral conductor wrapped around the ground rod might induce some unwanted current on the event of a ground fault that might be harmful rather than beneficial.
Hopefully someone more knowledgeable can shed some light on whether having a coil of wire around the grounding rod has a positive or negative impact or if it doesn't make much of a difference. Thanks in advance!

what is the wire connected to?

If it isn't too late, use a Ufer ground. Way better.

@jsotola it will be connected to the rod itself with a clamp along with the insulated wire that will be connected to the earth busbar in the distribution panel

@periblepsis Thanks for the suggestion, in fact the entire rod + wire wrapped around it will be encased in a 4" pillar made of conductive concrete and the conductivity of the surrounding soil will be chemically enhanced, perhaps this configuration is used to somehow mimic an ufer ground?

@chomba Sounds still better but 4" isn't much. The Ufer grounds I build here make up the entire concrete foundation of the building, using rebar clamped tightly together throughout. But what you say sounds better than just burying what I saw with soil. So that's good.

@periblepsis Ended up burying it in a 6'' pillar of conductive concrete but the surrounding area is very rocky and got 15 ~ 16 ohms in the ground resistance test which is still below the 25 ohms limit allowed by local regulation but was hoping to get close to 10 ohms. Will probably bury another rod in the future and connect them together to see if that gets me below 10 ohms.

@chomba I saw that photo. If that is representative of your site then I'm not surprised. Concrete here is basically a wet sponge. So even your system would be very good. But i still like to use the entire building foundation and a matrix of rebar. One or several pieces are bent to stick out, vertically, to provide something to clamp into within the later built walls. Appreciate the update! Thanks.

I can't think of any ways it would hurt, it will increase conduction to the soil which is the purpose of a grounding rod.
You might get some mutual inductance between conductors in the event of a fault, but that isn't going to affect the operation AFAIK

What about radiated emissions? This looks like one big (likely very poor) transformer but the currents passing through it are considerable. Suppose we have some washing machine or whatever installed just above it.

@Lundin why would there be any current at all flowing through this ground rod under normal circumstances?

You probably won't get much current during normal operation, you do get some from any RF flowing down ground or any leakage current from devices which should be small. It's really the fault that would cause a lot of current. I wouldn't expect a lot of radiated emissions due to the low impedance but adding a bit of inductance on the end is probably nulled by the increased conductivity to ground.

Electrically, it looks like a great idea. Quite aesthetic from the picture to be honest. To bad it will be covered in dirt, sand and gravel... Anyway, when it comes to ground rods (helices?) more copper (surface area in contact with planet earth) is always better (from a performance standpoint). Obviously it will cost more than just a spike, but the reason this is done is to compensate for poor conductivity of the earth (ground - literally the local earth) due to poor soil/sand dry conditions. More surface area equals more contact with the ground which amounts to lower resistance. Lower resistance means lower voltage drop during fault conditions so the potential difference tends to zero with more copper.
In the US, we usually just add an extra spike or two (or more with terrible "dirt" conditions).
